# Joint Probability Distibutions

Tags: probability, random-variables, variance

Let X and Y be jointly distributed random variables. Define $W = 2X+3Y$.

(a) What is $E(W)$?
(b) What is $Var (W)$?
(c) What is $Var W$ when $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

For this, I used the property $E(aX+bY) = aE(X)+b(Y)$ to get the answer for (a).  For (b) and (c) I used the property that $Var(aX+bY)= a^2Var(X) + b^2Var(Y)$, however, I think it only applies for (c) because X and Y are independent. Is this correct? If not what theorem should I use for (b)? Should I also indicate the discrete and continuous cases for (a) (b) and (c)? What does it mean also to 'Define $W= 2X +3Y$? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. $$Var(2X+3Y) = 4Var(X) + 9Var(Y) + 12Cov(X,Y).$$

So, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $Cov(X,Y) = 0$. then $Var(W) = 4Var(X) + 9Var(Y)$.

Comment: Okay, do you think I need to distinguish the formulas for the expected value and variance since they have different formulas for continuous and discrete RV? @GAVD

Comment: @AC18, no linearity of expectation, and bilinearity of covariance apply to both continuous and discrete random variables.  The same formula apply to both independent and dependent variables too; it is just that the covariance for independent random variables is zero.